# Prevent multiple form submission using PRG?

Tags: zend-framework2, post-redirect-get

I need to get rid of the 'Confirm Resubmission' dialog box to prevent multiple form submissions, and also for the form validation errors automatically rendered by ZF2 to be cleared when the user refreshes the page.

I have read on ZF2's Documentation on the PRG plugin but I'm not sure how to implement it when I still want to display form errors.

This is my current code:

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $sm                 = $this->getServiceLocator();
    $forms              = $this->getForms();
    $viewModel          = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('customer/customer/view-login-reg-form.phtml');
    $this->layout()->setVariable('title', 'Welcome!');
    $viewModel->setVariables($forms);

    $request            = $this->getRequest();
    if($request->isPost()) {
        $postData       = $request->getPost();
        $forms['formLogin']->setData($postData);
        $forms['formLogin']->setInputFilter($sm->get('Customer\Form\Filter\LoginFilter')->getInputFilter());

        if ($forms['formLogin']->isValid()) {
            $data       = $forms['formLogin']->getData();
            $customer   = $this->getCustomerTable()->getCustomer($data['login-email'], $data['login-password']);

            if (empty($customer)) {
                $viewModel->setVariable('errorMessage', 'Account does not exist');

                return $viewModel;
            }

            $LoginService = $sm->get('Customer\Service\LoginService');
            $LoginService->initLogin($customer);

            $this->handleRedirect();
        }
    }

    return $viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Why would multiple submissions be a problem when there are form errors? If there are errors, it doesn't matter if the form gets resubmitted. The code you have looks fine.

Comment: @TimFountain They want me to get rid of the 'Confirm Resubmission' prompt for *all* forms (to be uniform?) to avoid double processing, e.g. double insertion of records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your method as follow :

```
public function loginAction()
{
    $prg = $this->prg();
    if ($prg instanceof Response) {
        return $prg;
    }
    // here, $prg is false if multiple submissions 
    if ($prg === false) {
        // your code for init $prg or redirect to other action
    }
    // here, $prg contains post and get parameters as an array
    // You must distinguish whether this is an entry to display the form 
    // or the return to process the data returned by the submit
    // because $request is no longer available. Example :
    $forms              = $this->getForms();
    if (array_key_exists('submit', $prg) {
        $forms['formLogin']->setData($prg);
        $forms['formLogin']->setInputFilter($sm->get('Customer\Form\Filter\LoginFilter')->getInputFilter());

        if ($forms['formLogin']->isValid()) {
            $data       = $forms['formLogin']->getData();
            $customer   = $this->getCustomerTable()->getCustomer($data['login-email'], $data['login-password']);

            if (empty($customer)) {
                $viewModel->setVariable('errorMessage', 'Account does not exist');

                return $viewModel;
            }

            $LoginService = $sm->get('Customer\Service\LoginService');
            $LoginService->initLogin($customer);

            $this->handleRedirect();
        }
    }
    $viewModel          = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate('customer/customer/view-login-reg-form.phtml');
    $this->layout()->setVariable('title', 'Welcome!');
    $viewModel->setVariables($forms);
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Comment: I modified it a little but yeah it works. And thanks for the comments. :)

Comment: Hold on I have a question, is this only applicable for self-redirect? What if the form processing I need is in another route? Would it be possible to pass the POST data to that route? (And after the processing redirect the user to another page)

Comment: You can redirect to another route by `$this->prg($route, false)` or to another url by `$this->prg($url, true)`. In the target action, `$this->prg()` to get parameters (POST and GET).
After processing, to redirect the user to another route, `return $this->redirect()->toRoute($route, ['action' => $action]);`

Comment: Thank you! But then if my understanding is right: say I redirected to another route to process the form, and errors were discovered in the form validation, I'd have to carry those over (perhaps store in the session) to display them when I redirect back to the previous route (back to the form)?